# In CSS 2.1, if a parent establish a stacking context, why can the children's text go under the parent but the background color cannot?

Tags: css

This is an advanced CSS question.

In the JSFiddle:  (as tested on Chrome 26.0, Firefox 20.0, and IE 10)

http://jsfiddle.net/4yRrm/10

The parent establishes a stacking context, and the children have higher z-index than the parent and cover the parent up, so that's all fine.

But what about in http://jsfiddle.net/4yRrm/11

Now the children have a lower z-index than the parent.  The text of the children now go under that parent's text (as you can see the parent's text in blue color covering up the black color of the children's text), but why do the children's background color go **above** the parent instead?  Please substantiate your answer with the spec.  Why is there such a behavior -- does that achieve a certain purpose?

As it is, the background of the parent is the lowest layer, and then the children's background, and then the children's text, and then the parent's text.  So the parent's painting are at the "extreme end" -- the background as the lowest layer, and the text as the topmost layer, and the children's content are "sandwiched" inside these two extremes.

And related is: how do you make the parent go above the children **completely** even for the backgrounds, when the parent establishes a stacking context?  Please do not answer to remove the `positive: relative` or to remove the `z-index: 0` of the parent, as that will fail to establish a stacking context for the children.  That is, the parents MUST have a `position` of either `relative`, `absolute`, or `fixed`, and at the same time, have a `z-index` of an integer (and cannot be `auto`).

Comment: By the way, if you would like to see the background and border painted at the same time and in action: http://jsfiddle.net/4yRrm/15/

Answer (score 5):

CSS2.1 [states](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#layers):

> Each box belongs to one *stacking context*. Each positioned box in a given stacking context has an integer *stack level*, which is its position on the z-axis relative other stack levels within the same stacking context. Boxes with greater stack levels are always formatted in front of boxes with lower stack levels. Boxes may have negative stack levels. Boxes with the same stack level in a stacking context are stacked back-to-front according to document tree order.
>
> Within each stacking context, the following layers are painted in back-to-front order:
>
> 1. the background and borders of the element forming the stacking context.
> 2. the child stacking contexts with negative stack levels (most negative first).
> 3. the in-flow, non-inline-level, non-positioned descendants.
> 4. the non-positioned floats.
> 5. the in-flow, inline-level, non-positioned descendants, including inline tables and inline blocks.
> 6. the child stacking contexts with stack level 0 and the positioned descendants with stack level 0.
> 7. the child stacking contexts with positive stack levels (least positive first).

As you can see from items 1 and 2, the child stacking contexts with negative stack levels (i.e. your child elements) are always painted above the background of the current stacking context (i.e. your parent element).

The text of the parent element is then painted above the child elements, as in item 5.

It is not possible to make a stacking context sit completely above any of its descendants — its background and borders will *always* be painted at the very bottom no matter what you do. Since a box may only appear in one stacking context at a time (stacking contexts can be nested but that's not relevant here), you'll have to move those elements out of the parent stacking context if you want them to sit completely under the parent, while allowing the parent to establish its own stacking context for its other contents. For example, you can move them just outside the parent such that they become siblings instead, sharing the same stacking context which in your case is the root stacking context.

Comment: so I think (1) to (7) essentially says: the element forming the stacking context will always have its background and border painted first, and then the negative `z-index` children, and then its own content, and then any children with `z-index` `auto` and `0`, and then the positive `z-index` children.

Comment: So we can think of a parent establishing a stacking context painting with these z-indexes: its background and border having z-index of `-infinity`, and its content having a z-index 0, and then any children with `z-index` `auto` and `0`, and then children with positive `z-index`, so no matter what the z-index is for the parent, that is related to the outside stacking context.  Its z-index relative to the stacking context it just created, is always `0`

Answer (score 3):

Very interesting question:

- **Why is there such a behavior?**

  Based on the definitions,

  http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#z-index
  and

  http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/zindex.html

  If you follow the steps, it gets rendered as it is defined.

[image: Stacking Context]

(Image from http://www.vanseodesign.com/css/css-stack-z-index/)

> Within each stacking context, the following layers are painted in
>   back-to-front order:
>
> 1- the background and borders of the element forming the stacking context.
>   
>   2- the child stacking contexts with negative stack levels (most negative first).
>   
>   3- the in-flow, non-inline-level, non-positioned descendants.
>   
>   4- the non-positioned floats.
>   
>   5- the in-flow, inline-level, non-positioned descendants, including inline tables and inline blocks.
>   
>   6- the child stacking contexts with stack level 0 and the positioned descendants with stack level 0.
>   
>   7- the child stacking contexts with positive stack levels (least positive first).

- **How do you make the parent go above the children completely even for the backgrounds, when the parent establishes a stacking context?**

  If a standard browser is following the definition, then you can't do that for a **stacking context** and its children, because that would be in conflict with the definition.

Answer (score 0):

Your text node :

`Hello Chip Hello Chip Hello Chip Hello Chip`

also gains a stacking context :

1. `#chip01` : `imaginary-stack-context: 0`
2. `#chip01 "Hello Chip..."` - `imaginary-stack-context: 1`
3. `#chip02` - `imaginary-stack-context: 0`
4. `#chip03` - `imaginary-stack-context: 0` ( since you have `z-index: -1` makes it behind all other elements with `positive` / `auto` z-indexes. )

The CSS 2.1 specs were given already by @BoltClock.

[image]