# Nested z-index not working as expected

Tags: css, z-index

Why doesn't the red element go behind the blue one? This isn't making much sense to me. I've tried making the red element `z-index: -1` but that does not work.

http://jsfiddle.net/dmcgrew/6cY84/

Comment: For your "Why" question, read my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16504832/in-css-2-1-if-a-parent-establish-a-stacking-context-why-can-the-childrens-tex/16505305#16505305

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The red element is a child of the blue one, so it will always be in front. If you make this slight change your styles will work:

```
<div class="parent"></div>
<div class="child">child</div>
```

Now those two div's are "on the same level" and the red one's z-index becomes meaningful, which in your code it wasn't.