# How to bring background image to front?

Tags: css

I'm trying to make a list of "fake video" which is actually an image with a play icon on it. My idea is set the play icon as background, then bring it to front of the image using z-index, however, no matter what I do the, icon still stay behind any content within the tag.

This is my code:

HTML:

```
<ul>
    <li><img src="http://www.mytinyphone.com/uploads/users/fairytail123/574523.jpg"/></li>
    <li>test</li>
    <li>test</li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
li { 
    font-size:25px; 
    background:url(http://www.chicagotribune.com/hive/images/video/play_icon_carousel.png);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    z-index:99999;
}
```

Here is a jsfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/ZNeFu/

Comment: `z-index` works on positioned elements only. Just add `position:relative`...

Comment: i am afraid it will not work with css background image...

Comment: you would have have the play icon in a separate element, whether as a background or inline image, either way you could then use z-index to position that element on top of the other.

Comment: @Mee On why your current solution doesn't work, read my answer here regarding stacking context and z-index http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16504832/in-css-2-1-if-a-parent-establish-a-stacking-context-why-can-the-childrens-tex/16505305#16505305

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use a pseudo element (or another absolutely positioned element) to achieve this.

[**JSFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/ZNeFu/5/)

**HTML**

```
<ul>
    <li><img src="http://www.mytinyphone.com/uploads/users/fairytail123/574523.jpg"/>
    </li>
</ul>
```

**CSS**

```
li { 
    font-size:25px; 
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}

li:before {
    position: absolute;
    content:"";
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    background:url(http://www.chicagotribune.com/hive/images/video/play_icon_carousel.png);
    background-repeat:no-repeat; 
    background-position: center;
    background-size: contain;

}
```

Comment: just one problem here, this nests the li elements side by side

Comment: @FabioG. True but otherwise the `li` would be 100% wide of the viewport or parent element width. I would assume that in the actual live ennvironment that the `li` (or parent) would have an explicit widthh.

Answer (score 0):

every part of the page have have z-index usually the default is 0.
so any time you want to make something go in front you use z-index:1;
and anytime you want to take something to the back you use z-index:-1;
lets say you have to images one over the other ore anything else you can use z-index:2; or more.s
the integer mean what layer is the "item".
and also all of it depends on the position. in your case i would use absolute.
hope that was helpful to understand better layering properties.

Answer (score -1):

add `position:absolute;` that should do it

Or whatever `position` you require.

It's the position that allow the `z-index` to "move" the image.

Comment: I tried, not working. I edited my post add a jsfiddle, please take a look.