# How to layer box-shadows using z-index?

Tags: css

[codepen](http://cdpn.io/wqItA)

```css
#b {
  background: orange;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px black;
  z-index: 2;
  position: relative;
}

#c {
  background: red;
  z-index: 1;
  position: relative;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  position: relative;
}

li {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 2px 5px;
}

.current {
  background-color: orange;
  z-index: 3;
  position: relative;
}

#d {
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px black;
  z-index: 2;
}
```

```html
<div id="a">
  <div id="b">bbb</div>
  <div id="c">
    <ul>
      <li>a</li>
      <li class="current">b</li>
      <li>c</li>
      <li>d</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="d">dddd
</div>
```

Take a look at the code pen. I've got the layers more or less how I want it, except I want the "b" tab to be above the box-shadow caused by the orange div above.

To elaborate, the orange `#b` div should cast a shadow on the red `#c` div, the `.current` tab should appear flush with the orange `#b` div (have no shadow on it), and `#d` should *not* cast a shadow on `#c` at all.

The problem is that the `z-index` on `.current` doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

**Demo:** http://codepen.io/anon/pen/vLgKC

*Tip*: Make sure `position` is **explicitly** set on elements with `z-index` e.g. `relative` etc, even if you're fine with the default, it has to be set.

For more info on `z-index` and stacking context and the priorities please see my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16504832/in-css-2-1-if-a-parent-establish-a-stacking-context-why-can-the-childrens-tex/16505305#16505305).

The above, combined with the `inset` for `box-shadow`

> **inset**

If not specified (default), the shadow is assumed to be a drop shadow (as if the box were raised above the content).
The presence of the inset keyword changes the shadow to one inside the frame (as if the content was depressed inside the box).
Inset shadows are drawn inside the border (even transparent ones), above the
background, but below content.

And a `negative spread`

> **spread-radius**
>
> This is a fourth  value. Positive values will cause the shadow to expand and grow bigger, negative values will cause the
> shadow to shrink. If not specified, it will be 0 (the shadow will be the same size as the element).

(Both [here](http://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-shadow))

Will give you the effect that you are looking for.

So you will need to change the place that the shadows are applied on elements.

So the final CSS:

```css
   #b {
      background: orange;
      z-index: 2;
      position: relative;
    }
    
    #c {
      background: red;
      -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 10px 10px -10px black;
      -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 10px 10px -10px black;
      box-shadow: inset 0 10px 10px -10px black;
      z-index: 1;
      position: relative;
    }
    
    ul {
      list-style: none;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      z-index: 1;
      position: relative;
    }
    li {
      display: inline-block;
      padding: 2px 5px;
    }
    
    .current {
      background-color: orange;
      z-index: 3;
      position: relative;
    }
    
    #d {
      box-shadow: 0 0 10px black;
      z-index: 2;
    }
```

```html
<div id="a">
  <div id="b">bbb</div>
  <div id="c">
    <ul>
      <li>a</li>
      <li class="current">b</li>
      <li>c</li>
      <li>d</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="d">dddd
</div>
```

Comment: Using an inset shadow to create the illusion that another element has cast a shadow on the current one is a highly useful CSS trick! Great for circumstances where the DOM order that achieves the right shadowing look is wrong for tab order, etc.

Comment: It works like a charm. Thank you for great solution.

Comment: Explicit position did the trick. We are still talking about HTML right?

Answer (score 41):

If you're using z-index, make sure the element has a defined position attribute or it won't work. Wherever you use z-index in your css, define the position of that element. (Absolute, relative, inherit...)

Comment: Did I miss putting `position: relative` somewhere that I'm not seeing?

Comment: This answer is not correct/relevant for this question; OP has added `position` values to all of the relevant elements already.

Answer (score 2):

Try using inset box-shadow on list elements and when a selected element has class `.current` then remove the inset shadow from it.

Comment: `inset` doesn't quite give the effect I want. Also, it would have to be applied to `#c`, not the li's (I want the shadow across the whole bar).