# Z-Index issue with before and after of elements

Tags: css, z-index

Got a problem involving z-index. I'm stuck!

I got a container with a background gradient. On top of it I got a shape (a hexagon) made with a square (a div) and two triangles (before and after of the div). On top of the div I should have an image and on top of the image I should have a ribbon. The problem (as you can see in the JS Fiddle) is that the before/after of the ribbon and the shadows of it (which are made from the before and after of the text) are on top of the shape not beneath it.

```
<section class="packages">
    <article class="package">
        <div class="hexagon">
            <span class="text">See More</span>
            <div class="ribbon">
                <span class="title">Title 1</span>
            </div>
            <img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/1/1f/Flat_UI_-_book.png"
            class="image" />
        </div>
    </article>
</section>
```

My question is, what do I need to change in order for the end result to look as in the pic that I shared beneath? Hope you can help! Thanks!

This is a link to a JS Fiddle with the problem:
http://jsfiddle.net/vladimir04/afqf5sav/

And here is a link to a pic of how it should look:
http://i57.tinypic.com/4zucys.png

Comment: Have you tried breaking up the ribbon into two parts (one that goes right under the text and one that goes right under the hexagon)?

Comment: What about just changing the width of the before and after ribbon elements to something like width: 1.64em;

Comment: You can't get a child element behind the background color of the "root" of its the stacking context. And that's by definition and how it works. Read my answer here regarding stacking context and z-index http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16504832/in-css-2-1-if-a-parent-establish-a-stacking-context-why-can-the-childrens-tex/16505305#16505305 You will need to change the way you are trying to achieve it. Like having an extra element for the "background color" part instead of a background-color on the root.

Comment: @Arbel Thanks for the answer, I removed the bg of the parent I inserted a div sibling to ribbon with the background color and it worked! Your explanation was also very good. One question tho', do you have any idea why in the original example the ribbon managed to go behind the :before and :after of the parent element but not the parent element itself? Is there a particular behavior for :before and :after pseudo-elements?

Comment: Glad to be of help. As I said you can't get a child element behind the background color of the "root" of its stacking context, this applies to the ribbon, it doesn't have anything to do with :before and :after. Also a pseudo element is still counted as a child element of its parent.