# Writing to a canvas breaks the resizing of the wrapping div on Safari only

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, canvas

I have a `div` wrapping a `canvas`. I want to be able to resize the `div`. Im using `resize: "both"` and `overflow: "auto"` on the wrapping `div`. This works fine on Chrome, but bizarrely, on Safari, if I write anything to the canvas, I now CANNOT resize the `div`. The cursor also no longer changes when I hover over the resize animation in the bottom right.

The code is:

```
function Base() {

  React.useEffect(() => {
    const canvas = document.getElementById("covering-canvas-11");
    const context = canvas.getContext("2d");

    console.log("context for convercaning canvas 11 is ", context);

    if (context) {
      context.clearRect(0, 0, 40, 40);
      context.fillStyle = "white";
    }
  });

  return (
    <div>
        <div
          style={{
            resize: "both",
            overflow: "auto",
            background: "#ccc",
            width: "40px",
            height: "40px",
          }}
        >
          <canvas id={`covering-canvas-11`} width="40px" height="40px"></canvas>
        </div>
    </div>
  );
}
ReactDOM.render(
  <Base />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

The CodePen is here: https://codepen.io/mark-kelly-the-looper/pen/gOjwjyz

This works on Chrome, I can hover over the `div` and expand it. But not on Safari. When I comment out the `useEffect` so there is no longer any writing to the `canvas` and check on Safari - now the `div` can be resized!

EDIT:
CodePen with drawing to the canvas (div is NOT resizable on Safari): https://codepen.io/mark-kelly-the-looper/pen/rNrMELR

[image]

CodePen without drawing to canvas (div IS resizable in Safari): https://codepen.io/mark-kelly-the-looper/pen/rNrMELR

EDIT:

Im using Safari 14.0.3. If others cannot reproduce this issue, please comment.

EDIT
My app allows users to draw shapes on the canvas, so canvas listens mouse move, mouse down, mouse up events.

[image]

Comment: I can repro in Safari 16, seems to be related with the scrollbars. If you change your System Settings > Appearance > Show scroll bars: Always it's always resizable. Otherwise, scrolling a bit in the canvas before trying to resize also makes it work. Not sure why drawing on the context has any influence though, but anyway, please raise an issue at https://bugs.webkit.org

Comment: thanks, i wonder is there a neat way around this bug

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bug and it's reproducible.

To fix it in Safari, add this to your `canvas` styles.

```
position: relative;
z-index: -1;
```

And this to the container `div`.

```
position: relative;
z-index: 0;
```

Modify the values for `position` and the `z-index` based on your real needs. But keep the combination and a negative value for `z-index` of the `canvas`, and `0` or more for the container `div`.

So targeting Safari only, your code becomes:

```
function Base() {

   React.useEffect(() => {
     const canvas = document.getElementById("covering-canvas-11");
     const context = canvas.getContext("2d");

     console.log("context for convercaning canvas 11 is ", context);

     if (context) {
       context.clearRect(0, 0, 40, 40);
       context.fillStyle = "9ff";
       context.fillRect(0, 0, 40, 40);
     }
   });
  
function handleCanvasClick(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  console.log('You clicked the canvas.');
}

const canvasSafariCSS = `
  /* CSS targeting Safari only */
  @media not all and (min-resolution:.001dpcm) {
    .canvas-container {
      position: relative;
      z-index: 0;
    }
    .canvas-container canvas {
      position: relative;
      z-index: -1;
    }
  }
`;

  return (
    <div>
        <style>{canvasSafariCSS}</style>
        <div
          className = "canvas-container"
          style={{
            resize: "both",
            overflow: "auto",
            background: "#ccc",
            width: "40px",
            height: "40px",
          }}
        >
          <canvas id={`covering-canvas-11`} width="40px" height="40px"
            onClick = {handleCanvasClick}
          ></canvas>
        </div>
    </div>
  );
}
ReactDOM.render(
  <Base />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

---

### **More explanation**

The gist of this method is to [establish a stacking context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16504832/in-css-2-1-if-a-parent-establish-a-stacking-context-why-can-the-childrens-tex/16505305#16505305) (and [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Positioning/Understanding_z_index/The_stacking_context)) for the container `div` and keep the `position` and a negative `z-index` for the `canvas`

So in essence, for the container `div`, aside from

```
position: relative;
z-index: 0;
```

Something like the following will work too:

```
transform: translateX(0);
```

or an `opacity` less than 1:

```
opacity: 0.99;
```

or even:

```
will-change: opacity;
```

e.g.

```
function Base() {

   React.useEffect(() => {
     const canvas = document.getElementById("covering-canvas-11");
     const context = canvas.getContext("2d");

     console.log("context for convercaning canvas 11 is ", context);

     if (context) {
       context.clearRect(0, 0, 40, 40);
       context.fillStyle = "9ff";
       context.fillRect(0, 0, 40, 40);
     }
   });
  
function handleCanvasClick(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  console.log('You clicked the canvas.');
}

const canvasSafariCSS = `
  /* CSS targeting Safari only */
  @media not all and (min-resolution:.001dpcm) {
    .canvas-container {
      will-change: opacity;
    }
    .canvas-container canvas {
      position: relative;
      z-index: -1;
    }
  }
`;

  return (
    <div>
        <style>{canvasSafariCSS}</style>
        <div
          className = "canvas-container"
          style={{
            resize: "both",
            overflow: "auto",
            background: "#ccc",
            width: "40px",
            height: "40px",
          }}
        >
          <canvas id={`covering-canvas-11`} width="40px" height="40px"
            onClick = {handleCanvasClick}
          ></canvas>
        </div>
    </div>
  );
}
ReactDOM.render(
  <Base />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Comment: `z-index` needs to be wrapped as a string here, or it'll SyntaxError, but anyway, `z-index: -1` is NOT "harmless" at all, it will hide the canvas behind the resizable `<div>`. OP has a background-color on that resizable div, and certainly, they will draw something else than transparent pixel on their canvas, something they'll probably want to not be hidden.

Comment: @Kaiido Corrected the syntax, thanks. Also made an update to cover this specific DOM structure and modified the language to prevent confusion.

Comment: Thanks. I should have clarified in the question, I want to allow users to be able to draw on the canvas. With your solution, they wont be able to....

Comment: @Mark I updated the code to target Safari only, as an example. So with this the `canvas` is visible and receives the pointer events and your original issue is solved, too.

Answer (score 2):

The issue seems to be that the `<canvas>` will create some overflow in the resizable parent, and when its been drawn on it, it will have an higher z-index than the resize handle.
Always showing the scrollbars would avoid that bug, but to workaround it easily, you can disable the pointer-events on the `<canvas>`. This way you'll always be able to interact with the resize handle:

```js
const ctx = document.querySelector("canvas").getContext("2d");
ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 1, 1);
```

```css
.resizer {
  overflow: auto;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  resize: both;
  background: #CCC;
}
:checked ~ .resizer > canvas {
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<input type=checkbox id=check checked><label for=check>Apply fix</label>
<div class=resizer>
  <canvas></canvas>
</div>
```

But that should be considered a bug, so please file an issue at https://bugs.webkit.org

Comment: Thanks. The issue here is I allow users to draw shapes on the canvas, so listen for mouse move, mouse down, mouse up. `pointer-events: none;` presumably would prevents users from being able to draw on the canvas?

Comment: Listening on the canvas is generally frowned upon, it's often better to listen on a container, so that you can get events on the border of the canvas (particularily useful with wide brushes).

Comment: I did not know that, my app has been going for years with events on the canvas. I'll try listening on the container.